# How to display a UIActionSheet Item after UIActionSheet closes

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

How do I display the item selected from a UIActionSheet?  This an android example but I am trying to implement this in an iPhone.  I want to tap the button below the Flower Quantity value and have it open a UIActionSheet, let the user pick an item then display the item selected after the UIActionSheet closes

[image: android spinner example of selection]
[image: android selection]

Answer (score 1):

How about a grouped table with two items and a `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` next to the active item?

Comment: Will this first display a single item and then when tapped show the two choices, allow one to be selected, and then show just the single, selected item?  I have not wrttien any iOS anything yet and just starting to plan and to figure out how my layouts and gui will act.  Any code samples or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, it'll show both options with the currently selected one checked. If you require that only the selected choice is displayed, you might consider a `UIPopoverController` with the table embedded in it.

Comment: cant find iphone version.  In one routine I have 200 entries with each entry having a choice of two things.  This is why I am planning now because I need to be sure iOS can do what I am after.  It pushed the limits of android but I got it done and I customized the view too.

Comment: How about a screenshot of what you have on Android?

Comment: A `UIPickerView` is the closest iOS equivalent. A `UIActionSheet` might be good as well. Also, with a bit of control re-layout, a `UISegmentedControl` with the two options in it might be great.

Comment: UIActionSheet looks more promising.  I am off to explore its implementation.